# Interactive web workflows

Tags: web-development, framework, workflow

I am looking for some framework to build interactive web workflows.

#### My problem:

I have a lot of .doc files with orientation for users, some docs have 200 pages and the users should read it to help them act in some scenario. Most of the users don't read it because it is too long and/or because it is hard to see the whole thing and go straight for what they want.

#### My proposal:

Create a web workflow. With boxes, connectors, action boxes, so the user could navigate more easily, and highlight the path the user choose. The web workflow should allow an admin to create it inline and allow users to navigate.

#### Objective:

The users will get the information easier using the workflow rather than using the .doc.

---

I am using Bootstrap as a framework and would be cool if workflow could use it in some way.

Comment: Why not just use HTML and hyperlinks? Do you want to force the user to go only according to the steps you designed?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, for the question: No. The users could go to the path they want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a programmable solution I recommend taking a look at the [Django web framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and one of [workflow automation libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django/25717038#25717038).

You are probably flow bound to single user, in this case [django-flows](https://github.com/carlio/django-flows) will suit you well.

Comment: The concept of django-flows looks like the thing I am looking for. But I couldn't find a way to test it online. Is it possible?